# Is it possible to send the google spreadsheet data to another application without using button click event?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to send the google sheet data to another application, using any trigger like onEdit. i am now able to send the data on a button click event, but now i want to do this without using any button little more automatic. it should be done just on cell edit.i've tried this can anybody please help.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");

function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('cellTracker')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}

function cellTracker(){
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getCellValue();
          if((ss.getActiveCell().getValue()) > 0  && (ss.getActiveCell().getValue()) == Cell){
     var link = app.createAnchor('XXXXX',"http://###############/noetic_Data/AddDataToAras?data="+Cell);
         } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a spreadsheet by id, you could in this case attach a script to a spreadsheet by opening Tools -> Script editor -> Blank Project. This will open the script editor where you can use the onEdit trigger with this code:

```
function onEdit(e){
    var myRange = e.range;            //get the range that's edited
    var myValue = myRange.getValue(); //get the value of the first cell in the range 

    //send data to other application 
}
```

Every time you update a range (mostly just one cell) in your spreadsheet, this trigger wil use the event object containing the range and it's data.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

To see what's going on you can use the logger. For example:

```
Logger.log(myValue);
```

Comment: I've added some explanation.

Comment: i am also trying to send data to a link. using time scheduler trigger. is it possible, please help.

Comment: You can set up a trigger in your script editor by following Resources -> Current project's triggers. You can call your own function (for example cellTracker()) in this trigger.

Comment: hi pisctor, i tried the one example u've gave but its not working. i tried something like this code given bellow, but i m not getting how to like attach the link to the cell. like the data of the cell should go directly to that link. hope u understood what i need thanks for helping

Comment: [Link](https://script.google.com/macros/d/M5vmICvkowrSJWFaqRiDzulZgXXfbkfm2/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvFqaCktMRqdyY68cnGecuwu_9Nn8xIgYdow4sJtPtyklnv0vOVsP7gEeolfzJ21_PW6NEyhW-RONAja3oW5TtdR3K6QJy16_iSbuooDJisbPdyb75ZrWjwgGcFiekETwSNw2SWz25A) ---cheers